# Run Unit tests in MLengine ( returns unrecognized arguments: --job-dir)

Tags: google-cloud-ml

Im constantly using [ml-engine][1] as my production environment, and i'm now looking to run within it unit tests using the `unittest` package.

Here is my running script (run_tests.py):

```
import unittest
from fruad_score_other_subpackage.fruad_score_globals import globals
logger = globals['logger']

class Test_all_flow(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_supervised_model_has_varianve_in_results(self):
        unique_prediction_count=2
        self.assert_(unique_prediction_count>0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info('No Running:') #Just to make sure ml engine is running
    unittest.main()
```

And here is the bash script that runs it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

   export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=".......json"
    PROJECT_ID='.....'
    BUCKET_ID='machine_learning_datasets/fruad_score'
    now=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    JOB_NAME="fruad_score_testing__$now"
    JOB_DIR="gs://machine_learning_datasets/fruad_score"
    REGION="us-east1"
    PYTHON_VERSION='3.5'
    RUNTIME_VERSION='1.12'

    TRAINER_PACKAGE_PATH="./trainer/"
    PACKAGE_STAGING_PATH="gs://machine_learning_datasets/fruad_score"
    CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python"
    PACKAGES="globalclass-0.1.tar.gz"
    MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE="trainer.run_tests"

    gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
      --job-dir $JOB_DIR \
      --package-path $TRAINER_PACKAGE_PATH \
      --packages $PACKAGES \
      --module-name $MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE \
      --region $REGION \
      --runtime-version=$RUNTIME_VERSION \
      --python-version=$PYTHON_VERSION \
      --config trainer/config/config_train.json \
```

Looking at the logs, im getting the following error:

```
No Running:
.....
run_tests.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --job-dir
```

Which indicates that the process ran, but crashed when it activated `unittest.main()`

Why didn't it run the test ? why does it suddenly ask for job-dir (Notice that job id is passed within the `--job-dir` flag) ? is there any other way to run tests on ML engine?

Comment: We passed the flag job-dir to your code if you specify it in the job request (you actually did it). You need to either define a flag for job-dir or remove it from your job request.

Comment: I tried removing it and got `ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.jobs.submit.training) If local packages are provided, the `--staging-bucket` or `--job-dir` flag must be given`

Comment: It's because gCloud needs to stage your code in a gcs bucket. Can you replace --job-dir with --staging-bucket please?

Comment: @GuoqingXu It worked indeed, please post your answer, could you also elaborate why your solution worked?